# PingIDs (Data) is different on different sides

Tags: java, networking, io, minecraft, packets

I am working on a server software for Minecraft: Pocket Edition. Right now I am working on the MOTD for the server, and it works Just fine. When sending a response to a ping packet (0x01) with a 0x1c. It shows up in the world list with the name just fine. But, for some reason, If I send the same data from another program, the Ping ID and ServerID will show different in the consoles. Why is this?

Ping response code:

```
public PingResponse(DatagramPacket Packet, long ServerID) throws IOException {
    // Data from Ping
    ByteBuffer ReceivedPing = ByteBuffer.wrap(Packet.getData());

    // Set variables
    this.ServerID = ServerID;
    this.ServerName = ServerPropertiesHandler.getMOTD();
    this.PingID = ReceivedPing.getLong();

    // Server Name
    String Identifier = "MCCPP;MINECON;" + ServerPropertiesHandler.getMOTD();
    ByteBuffer PingResponseBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(35 + (short) Identifier.length());

    // Put Packet ID
    PingResponseBuffer.put(PacketIDList.ID_UNCONNECTED_PING_OPEN_CONNECTIONS);

    // Ping ID
    PingResponseBuffer.putLong(this.PingID);
    System.out.println("Ping ID: " + this.PingID);

    // Server ID
    PingResponseBuffer.putLong(this.ServerID);
    System.out.println("Server ID: " + this.ServerID);

    // Sugar Spice and everything nice
    PingResponseBuffer.put(PacketIDList.MAGIC);

    // Server Name
    PingResponseBuffer.putShort((short) Identifier.length());
    PingResponseBuffer.put(Identifier.getBytes());

    // Send
    PacketHandler.Socket.send(new DatagramPacket(PingResponseBuffer.array(), PingResponseBuffer.array().length), Packet.getAddress(), Packet.getPort());
}
```

Client Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // SEND
        final long PacketID = new Random().nextLong();
        DatagramSocket ClientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        ByteBuffer PingBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(25);
        PingBuffer.put(PacketIDList.ID_CONNECTED_PING_OPEN_CONNECTIONS);
        PingBuffer.putLong(PacketID);
        PingBuffer.put(PacketIDList.MAGIC);
        ClientSocket.send(new DatagramPacket(PingBuffer.array(), PingBuffer.array().length, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 19132));

        // RECEIVE
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1535];
        DatagramPacket PongPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        ClientSocket.receive(PongPacket);
        byte[] PongPacketData = PongPacket.getData();
        ByteBuffer PongBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(PongPacketData);
        if(PongPacketData[0] == (byte) 0x1c) {
            System.out.println("PingID From Server: " + PongBuffer.getLong());
            System.out.println("ServerID From Server: " + PongBuffer.getLong());
            System.out.println("MAGIC From Server: " + PongBuffer.get());
            System.out.println("MOTD From Server: " + PongBuffer.get());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("UNKNOWN PACKET");
        }
        ClientSocket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

3 months and no reply. pingID and serverID are identifiers of time used on respective systems to determine the time since start. These provide a double functionality. Firstly, they allow a server to determine any latency in the communications. Secondly, they help provide a packet order to commands. Rebooting a server would generate a new serverID starting from 0, while rejoining a server would provide a new pingID starting at 0.

I would be quite interested to see the progress you've made, as I've begun working on my own.

Comment: I am also working on similar project. When I connect to using my android client, it is not pinging the server.I used exactly the same way for reply message. Any idea

Comment: You may want to create a timer/thread to forcefully ping the server yourself every 1000ms or so, else you're only doing a pong (return ping).

Comment: Thank you @Komak57  , now it is working......there was a problem in sending packets from server